# Workflow XAML Intellisense VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, intellisense

I am trying to edit a TFS Workflow xaml file in Visual Studio and notice that intellisense is not working.  What xsd is required for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Intellisense is not supported for editing workflow XAML in Visual Studio 2010 (or at least Microsoft hasn't given us the XSD files to do so).

I do most of my editing in the Workflow Designer. Sometimes it's easier to make changes to the XAML directly (for maybe mass-renaming something), so I do some basic editing in the text editor, then switch back to the workflow designer to make sure that the workflow passes validation.

But if you are editing XAML directly all the time, you might want to consider just creating workflows in C#. You will get Intellisense there.

Perhaps this will be one of the features in the next version of Visual Studio.